# How do I find the size of a 2D array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I declare this array...

```
string[,] a = {
                  {"0", "1", "2"},
                  {"0", "1", "2"},
                  {"0", "1", "2"},
                  {"0", "1", "2"},
              };
```

Then I can measure the length with

```
a.Length
```

which is 12. How do I measure the dimension of the arrays within? If I try...

```
a[0].Length
```

I get `Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2`. What gives?

Comment: If you defined it as `string[][]` then `a[0].Length` would work.

Comment: Shouldn't `a.Length` be 12?

Comment: @PhilGan [Yes it should](http://ideone.com/br2Tth). Should we fix the OP? I don't know what etiquette demands here.

Comment: correction @Gabe: If you defined it as string[][] then a.Length would work.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You want the GetLength() method of your array:

```
a.GetLength(0);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx

Answer (score 65):

Use [`Array.Rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx) to get number of dimensions and then use [`Array.GetLength(int dimension)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) to get the length of a specific dimension.

Answer (score 17):

Use [System.Array.GetLength(int dimension)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx).