# C# Multidimensional Array Of Rectangles?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've hit a wall with this array of rectangles. I was fine with simply a one dimensional array but with one with 4 columns I've just started banging my head on my wall...

I've defined the array as:

```
private Rectangle[,] brick = new Rectangle[2, 8];
```

Then these are used in conjunction to that:

```
int[,] brickLocation = { {0, 0}, {0,21}, {0,42}, {0, 63}, {0, 84}, {0, 105}, {0, 126},
                             {61, 0}, {61,21}, {61,42}, {61, 63}, {61, 84}, {61, 105}, {61, 126} };
bool[] brickLive = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                       true, true, true, true, true, true, true };
```

And then trying to draw the rectangles through the multi array loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < brickLive.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < brickLive.Length; i++)
    {
        if (brickLive[i] == true)
        {
            brick[i, j] = new Rectangle(brickLocation[i, 0], brickLocation[i, 1], brkLength, brkHeight);
                    brickPaper.DrawRectangle(brickPen, brick[i, j]);
        }
        else
        {
            continue; //move onto next brick
        }
    }
}
```

It's stopped working and I can't think what I can do.... Can anyone help?

Comment: How exactly did it 'stop working'? Is there some error message or is the behaviour unexpected?

Comment: I get a IndexOutOfRangeException for the line: brick[i, j] = new Rectangle(brickLocation[i, 0], brickLocation[i, 1], brkLength, brkHeight);

Comment: you have i++ in your j for loop

Comment: Oh I did, still that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, in the lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < brickLive.Length; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < brickLive.Length; i++)
```

for the loops in the second line you mean to increase `j`, but you increase `i` instead.

Comment: Also he uses the Length-Property both times, which isnt correct either.

Comment: Yes, it should perhaps be `2` and `8`, as used for the creation of the array.

Comment: For the second time, what should I use instead of length()?

Comment: GetLength(0) and GetLength(1)

Comment: Access to thte lengths is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106369/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-2d-array-in-c)